# postgres - multiple table delete on same column (in each table)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
DELETE 
    i,
    l,
    dl,
    m
FROM
    creator.items i,
    creator.lists l,
    creator.display_lists dl,
    creator.maps m
WHERE
    account_id = 1;
```

But I get the errors:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "i"
LINE 2:     i,
```

is it actually possible to delete from multiple tables in postgres in one command or will I need to split it into four?

Comment: you can create foreign key with cascade delete

Comment: To add to the above, if you also post your table structure, maybe someone can give a formal answer.

Comment: You do have 2 other syntax errors, a missing `,` after `creator.lists l` and an extra one after `creator.maps m`

Comment: @Nick ah yep, but the error remains the same after the fix up

Comment: Try DELETE FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems clear from the docs that the DELETE-command is an operation to delete a set of rows from just one table. So yes, I would suggest that you need to split this into four separate DELETE-commands.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-delete.html